# Start a process in background, do a task, then kill the process in the background

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I have a script that looks like this:

```
pushd .
nohup java -jar test/selenium-server.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
cd web/code/protected/tests/
phpunit functional/
popd
```

The selenium servers needs to be running for the tests, however after the phpunit command finishes I'd like to kill the selenium-server that was running.

How can I do this?

Comment: @isalgueiro what if their are other processes running in the background?

Comment: `%1` stands for "first background job", and your script only sends one process to background http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html

Comment: @isalgueiro yeah but what if someone who is running the script has a background process already running in the terminal before running this script?

Comment: I don't think the script runs on the same shell instance. Anyway, if you don't want to rely on job number (i.e. `%1`) you can save `$!` after running nohup and kill the process by PID.

Comment: Then the best option would be run `kill %-` which will kill the last job

Comment: @nu11p01n73R which is better than, saving the PID like the one current answer says, or using the `kill %-` ?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R  Is there a reason for preferring `kill %-` rather than `kill %+` ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can probably save the PID of the process in a variable, then use the kill command to kill it.

```
pushd .
nohup java -jar test/selenium-server.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
serverPID=$!
cd web/code/protected/tests/
phpunit functional/
kill $serverPID
popd
```

I haven't tested it myself, I'd like to write it on a comment, but not enough reputation yet :)

Answer (score 7):

When the script is excecuted a  new shell instance is created. Which means that the `jobs` in the new script would not list any jobs running in the parent shell.

Since the `selenium-server` server is the only background process that is created in the new script it can be killed using

```
#The first job 
kill %1
```

Or

```
#The last job Same as the first one
kill %-
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't launch any other process in the background - which you don't - you can use $! directly:

```
pushd .
nohup java -jar test/selenium-server.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
cd web/code/protected/tests/
phpunit functional/
kill $!
popd
```